# blackberry OS6 widgets + jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, widget, blackberry-os6

I am trying latest jquery mobile (Alpha 4.1) in blackberry widget on OS6.  I love the "load-once" cache/ajax functionality of jQuery Mobile but not impressed with these implementation issues on BB.

I find the following issues:

- top of page (headers) disappear when
  pressing back button
- special effects (slides, pop) are
  lame or don't work.
- form elements change colors when
  clicked or focused.

Is there an alternative library with better visuals for BB?  I tried XUI but the ajax functionality broke with OS6.  I am also looking at UIU.

anyone?

Answer (score 0):

There's Sencha Touch you can try.

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

Comment: We are using bold 9700 (non touch). The touch models (Torch) are too fragile for our users.  What advantages does sencha touch have on BB?

Comment: does it replace jquery's ajax and manipulation functions or co-exist with jquery?

Comment: There's demo on the website you can try on BB. The Ext.js core does allow you to replace jQuery for ajax.